# What the requirements for the greyed-out skills/perks?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Alpha 17 comes with a completely revamped skill/perk system. A number of skills/perks, namely the crafting ones, are greyed out and unavailable at the beginning. I can't see how to unlock these skills/perks on the current UI. What are the requirements for these skills/perks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mouse over the little padlock icon to the right of the greyed out perk and it will tell you the requirements you need.